# separate_wider where first half becomes column name and second half becomes cell value

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

```
df <- data.frame(V_1 = c("null", "name:c", "name:d", "name:a", "name:k","name:A"),
                 V_2 = c("null", "cat:Y", "cat:Z", "cat:K", "cat:L","cat:K"))
```

I have a dataframe with multiple columns with key-value pairs like above.

I wish to separate the values of the cells, such that the 'key' becomes column name of a new column and 'value' becomes the value of the cell.

Expected output:

```
df2 <- data.frame(name = c("null", "c", "d", "a", "k","A"),
                  cat = c("null", "Y", "Z", "K", "L","K"))
df2
```

note that for my real dataframe I have several hundred columns, so I am looking for a solution that does not require manually typing column names but automatically generates the names based on the first half of the key:value pair.

Currently, I am splitting the key-value pairs using,

```
df3 <- df %>%
  separate_wider_delim(cols = everything(),
                       delim = ",",
                       too_few = "align_start",
                       names_sep = "")
```

but I do not know how to transform it properly so that the first half of the separated values become column names.

Comment: Notice that without the `key:value` pair, one cannot be able to tell where the `null` will be. it does not really matter whether column 1 has only `name:...` and column 2 has only `cat:...`. The method I provided does not look athe columns but rather at the key:value pair. So a column can have a mixture of key values, but still all the values will be placed under the correct key column

Comment: The solution I am looking for is to assume that a null in V_1 should occur at the same spot in 'column name' and a null in V_2 should be placed at the same spot in 'column cat', such that the final outcome is similar to df2 above.

Comment: check the edits below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Base R you could use `read.dcf` after pasteing all together:

```
a <- do.call(paste, c(sep="\n", collapse = "\n\n", df))
read.dcf(textConnection(a), all = TRUE)

  name cat
1    B   X
2    c   Y
3    d   Z
4    a   K
5    k   L
6    A   K
```

---

EDIT

```
setNames(data.frame(sub(".*:","", as.matrix(df))),gsub("(\\w+):.*|.", "\\1", df))
  name  cat
1 null null
2    c    Y
3    d    Z
4    a    K
5    k    L
6    A    K
```

Comment: This works for the original example but not the updated problem where the columns include null values (see above).

Comment: @Icewaffle null MUST also have the names, ie `"name:null"` etc. Otherwise how can null be null? Why should null be placed under `name` yet you do not have its value? And what is null here anyway? A string`"null"`? or `NA`??. This method would work even if you had different names for the same row. eg col1 had cat and col 2 had name in row 1 and col1 had name and col2 had cat in row 2. It would work even if you included a completely different text eg `people:good`.Whether the data is completely mixed up, misses some values in a row etc it will work

Comment: null is a string null, i.e. "null"

Comment: @Icewaffle well that string must have a column name before it. Without which you cannot tell where it belongs

Comment: both column V_1 and column V_2 each have entries with the string "null", see the update in the original post.

Comment: try `setNames(data.frame(sub(".*:","", as.matrix(df))),gsub("(\\w+):.*|.", "\\1", df))` Note that this will now make use of `regex`

Answer (score 2):

You may use the first row to get the column names, drop everything after colon.

To clean up the column value remove everything till the colon.

```
names(df) <- sub(':.*', '', unlist(df[1,]))
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) sub('.*:', '', x))
df

#  name cat
#1    B   X
#2    c   Y
#3    d   Z
#4    a   K
#5    k   L
#6    A   K
```

The second step can also be done using `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~sub('.*:', '', .)))
```

Comment: This works for the example posted, but in my real dataset where some rows have null values it breaks down. Do you have a modification if df is:

df <- data.frame(V_1 = c(null, "name:c", "name:d", "name:a", "name:k","name:A"),
                 V_2 = c(null, "cat:Y", "cat:Z", "cat:K", "cat:L","cat:K"))

to produce

```{r}
df2 <- data.frame(name = c(null, "c", "d", "a", "k","A"),
                  cat = c(null, "Y", "Z", "K", "L","K"))
df2
```?

Comment: @Icewaffle your updated dataframe is not reproducible. I am getting `object 'null' not found`

Comment: Apologies, here is the reproducible dataframe:

df2 <- data.frame(name = c("null", "c", "d", "a", "k","A"),                   
                  cat = c("null", "Y", "Z", "K", "L","K"))

Answer (score 1):

You don't always have to try to squeeze everything into a single step, two distinct steps could work just fine using more traditional tools:

```
get_col_names <- function(col){
  col_split <- stringr::str_split(string = col[1],pattern = ":")
  col_split[[1]][1]
}

new_cn <- sapply(df,get_col_names)
> df %>%
+   mutate(
+     across(.cols = everything(),
+            .fns = ~gsub("^.*:","",.x))
+     ) %>%
+   set_names(nm = new_cn)
  name cat
1    B   X
2    c   Y
3    d   Z
4    a   K
5    k   L
6    A   K
```

Comment: This does not produce the expected output, but instead produces:

```{r}
dfx <- data.frame(name = c("name:B", "name:c", "name:d", "name:a", "name:k","name:A"),
                 cat = c("cat:X", "cat:Y", "cat:Z", "cat:K", "cat:L","cat:K"))
```
```

Comment: @Icewaffle I would suggest trying again in a clean R session. It generates exactly the data frame you specified.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tidyverse solution: The second part is also provided by @Ronak Shah:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my_names <- df %>% 
  filter(if_any(everything(), ~.!="null")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  separate(value, into = c("a", "b")) %>% 
  pull(a) %>% 


df %>% 
  rename_with(~unique(my_names)) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~sub('.*:', '', .)))
```

```
 name  cat
1 null null
2    c    Y
3    d    Z
4    a    K
5    k    L
6    A    K
```